# What is the logic of else-if ladder statement?

Tags: c

I want to understand why in an if-else-if-else-if conditional, whenever the first if(condition) is true, every else if that follows is ignored and program terminates; 
To make it practical, bellow is the following code in C language:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = 10;

    if (a == 5)
        printf("Condition is false");
    else if (a == 6)
        printf("Condition is also false");
    else if (a == 7)
        printf("Condition is also false");
    else if (a == 10)
        printf("Condition is true");
    else if (a == 9)
        printf("Condition is also false");
    else
        printf("Condition is still false");
    return 0;
}
```

For example, if a were to be 5 instead of 10, then first if would evaluate to true, and the rest of the else-if would be considered false as a whole...if a were to be 10, then first every condition till else if(a==10) would evaluate to false, the statement under if(a==10) would be printed(because the condition is true), and then again, the following else-if and final else, will be all ignored. Why aren't all of them checked?

Is it because after each if, the following else virtually considers everything that's beneath it like a single statements and acts like it (like putting everything that follows an else into curly braces)?

Comment: Seems worth consulting a basic language reference first, e.g. [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) "_In the second form of `if` statement (the one including `else`), if `statement-true` is also an `if` statement then that inner `if` statement must contain an `else` part as well **(in other words, in nested `if`-statements, the `else` is associated with the closest `if` that doesn't have an `else`)**_"

Comment: @Fredrik Yeah, and the grammar was made to bind `else` to the closest `if` for that reason, presumably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why aren't all of them checked?

People have given you answers in terms of the definition of the C language, but that doesn't really tell you *why* an if-else chain behaves the way it does.  The designers of C decided it should be that way: why did they do that?  Also, in literally every other programming language that has `else if` at all, the designers made the same decision; why is that?

The answer is that it's more *useful* to have an else-if chain execute at most one of the clauses.  Let's take the infamous "fizzbuzz" programming exercise: here's one way to do it in C, using an if-else chain:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
        if (i % 15 == 0)
            puts("fizzbuzz");
        else if (i % 5 == 0)
            puts("buzz");
        else if (i % 3 == 0)
            puts("fizz");
        else
            printf("%d\n", i);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

This code *relies* on only one of the four clauses being executed.  Any number that is evenly divisible by 15 is also evenly divisible by 3 and 5; if the second and third clauses were also checked when the first was true, you'd get "fizzbuzz\nbuzz\nfizz\n" for all multiples of 15, instead of just "fizzbuzz\n" as you wanted.

But if you *want* a series of conditions to be tested independently, you can do that too: write a series of `if` statements *without* using `else`.  Here's another fizzbuzz implementation that uses that mechanism:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
        if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0) {
            if (i % 3 == 0)
                fputs("fizz", stdout);
            if (i % 5 == 0)
                fputs("buzz", stdout);
            putchar("\n");
        } else
            printf("%d\n", i);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Now we're relying on `i % 3 == 0` and `i % 5 == 0` being tested independently.

Answer (score 6):

The behavior you describe is the defined semantics of the `if` statement in the C language.

Here is your code reformatted with curly braces to make the structure more explicit:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = 10;

    if (a == 5) {
        printf("Condition is false");
    } else {
        if (a == 6) {
            printf("Condition is also false");
        } else {
            if (a == 7) {
                printf("Condition is also false");
            } else { 
                if (a == 10) {
                    printf("Condition is true");
                } else {
                    if (a == 9) {
                        printf("Condition is also false");
                    } else {
                        printf("Condition is still false");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above code is exactly equivalent to your example and shows how only a single `printf` may execute depending on the value of `a`. Another way to write this kind of selection is via a `switch` statement:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = 10;

    switch (a) {
      case 5:
        printf("Condition is false");
        break;
      case 6:
        printf("Condition is also false");
        break;
      case 7:
        printf("Condition is also false");
        break;
      case 10:
        printf("Condition is true");
        break;
      case 9:
        printf("Condition is also false");
        break;
      default:
        printf("Condition is still false");
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> Is it because after each if, the following else virtually considers everything that's beneath it like a single statements and acts like it (like putting everything that follows an else into curly braces?

Yes.

---

EDIT:

When an `if`, `else`, `while`, `for` statement is encountered, the thing that is conditionally (or repeatedly in the case of a loop) executed is the *block* that follows the statement. If you have a single command, then that command is the *block*. If you want multiple commands to be conditionally executed together, then you need to tie them together inside curly braces, but you don't need the braces for a single atomic command.

Now, an `if` statement, along with the block that it controls, is considered to be an atomic entity, i.e., a *block*. This includes its `else` statement and respective controlled block - it wouldn't make sense to treat them separately. So each time you write `else if`, you are starting an `else` block, which is made up of an `if` statement and all the code that the `if` clause controls. If you want to see it clearly, then you can wrap curly braces around that whole block, and it will end up looking like the reformatted code in the answers from @chqrlie and @ulricheckhardt.

That's the crude description of how it works, if you want something more accurate I suggest you read the standard.

Comment: So  Ulrich Eckhardt and @chqrlie, what you're implying is that compiler "virtually" puts curly braces after every else automatically ? Even if in my code there aren't any ? And then, act like after every else, curly braces are opened, and the whole content is spilled there and evaluated true/false as a simple printf statement ? ( like this : else { rest of content} ).

Comment: Consider @underscore_d's advise, read the standard, which is what is mandatory. Whether your interpretation with virtual curly braces is right depends on whether it matches the standard. I can't tell whether that's exactly what you mean.

Comment: Well @Ulrich Eckhardt, it's the if-else-if ladder concept....every example I've seen on the internet regarding this concept was without the curly braces after every else...yet your answers  include curly braces after each else, thus making your interpretation syntactically different than my code and the if-else-if ladder concept....this is what I don't understand....

Comment: @painkiller The curly braces don't change the behavior in these cases; they just make it easier to see the grouping.

Comment: @lxop, if "So each time you write else if, you are starting an else block, which is made up of an if statement and all the code that the if clause controls." explanation is to be applied to my particular example, it would mean that after the first else in my code a block will open and including in curling braces the rest of the code, or just the code to the next else ? and this rule apply after each else is the program ?

Comment: @painkiller it would mean that after the first `else` in your code, a block will open and include the next complete statement. In your case, this will be the next `if` construct, which includes *all* of the `if`, the positive block, the `else`, and the negative block. The negative block follows the same rules.

Comment: @ lxop, and the negative block, in your explanation would be this part of code ? :                          
           {
            if (a == 7) {
                printf("Condition is also false");
            } else { 
                if (a == 10) {
                    printf("Condition is true");
                } else {
                    if (a == 9) {
                        printf("Condition is also false");
                    } else {
                        printf("Condition is still false");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

Comment: The negative block is whatever is executed in the `else` case. So yes.

Answer (score 3):

Let me reformat that code for you:

```
if (a == 5) {
    printf("Condition is false");
} else {
    if (a == 6) {
        printf("Condition is also false");
    } else {
        if (a == 7) {
            printf("Condition is also false");
        } else {
            if (a == 10) {
                printf("Condition is true");
            } else {
                if (a == 9) {
                    printf("Condition is also false");
                } else {
                    printf("Condition is still false");
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```